# PHP, How can I sum-up the numeric values after calling a function from within a class?

Tags: php, class, oop, sum, function-pointers

The program deals 5 cards to each player displaying images of the cards along with the cards number value, after user selects number of players.

Everything works as described above, but I don't know how to total the values after calling the function. Can anyone give me an idea?

```
<?php

class classHand
{
    var $totals;
    var $cards;

    function drawCard($c, $theDeck)
    {
        if (is_numeric($c)) {
            $c = floor($c);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
                $this->cards[] = $theDeck->dealCard();
            }
        }
    }

    function showHand()
    {
        print("<table border=0>\n");
        print("<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>\n");
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->cards); $i++) {
            print("<td>" . $this->cards[$i]->getImage() . "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>\n");
        }
        print("</tr></table>\n");
    }

    function showValue()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->cards); $i++) {
            print("&nbsp;" . $this->cards[$i]->getValue() . "&nbsp;");
        }
    } // end of showValue
} // end of classHand

class classPlayer
{
    var $name;
    var $hand;

    function classPlayer($n = "player")
    {
        $this->name = $n;
        $this->hand = new classHand();
    }
}
```

Then this is the page that implements the classes called cards.php

```
<?php

include("classCard.php");

$dealersDeck = new classDeck();
$dealersDeck->shuffleDeck();

$player[] = new classPlayer("You");

$selected_players = $_POST['players'];

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($player); $j++) {
        $player[$j]->hand->drawCard(1, $dealersDeck);
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($player); $i++) {
    print("Player: " . $player[$i]->name . "<br />");
    $player[$i]->hand->showHand();
    $player[$i]->hand->showValue();
    print("<P>&nbsp;</p>");
}
```

Comment: Your class uses PHP4 coding style, beware that this is *very* outdated, and will even be removed in the next major version. please use the [`__constructor()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and the correct [property visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Hmmm... Thank you for the advice. That's something I've come to realize and will change up my code to fit the new style soon, but for now, with my code as is, is there a way to solve the initial problem I stated before in my post? I know there's a way. I just can't wrap my head around it. I'm doing it this way just to see if I can solve another issue from a different program for or less that use very old methods.

Comment: There is an example for sure, but it's a wall of text, with bad formatting, so as a lot of people, i'm not up for reading through all that. try to be concise in your question and the answers will follow soon. remove all irrelevant code, try to break it down to the smallest possible code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: OK I did it what you suggested. The formatting can't be edited at the momemt. Hopefully I can get a answer now from someone.

Comment: within the function `drawCard()` you can add the value of the card to the `$totals` variable and return it when you want within another function.

Comment: You might have overdone yourself ;)  it's not really clear now what function you are calling and where you want to get the totals. knowing the properties of the `Card` class would be useful. I've formatted the code.

Comment: JC Sama and NDM.thank you both for your help and information. When get home I will open my program and compare and test both of your code snippets and follow your explanations of the why and how and come back here to let you guys know what I've learned. Also NDM, I will add the properties of the card class back when I get home in a hour or so. The u again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$totals` property wasn't used, so I renamed it to `$totalValue`. In this variable, you keep track of the cards in the hand.

```
class Hand
{
    protected $totalValue;
    protected $cards;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reset();
    }

    /**
     * $deck is the only required parameter
     */
    public function drawCard($deck, $count = 1, $reset = false)
    {
        // reset the counter
        $this->reset();

        if (!is_numeric($count)) return;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $ccount; $i++) {
            $this->addCard($deck->dealCard());
        }
    }

    public function addCard(Card $card)
    {
        $this->totalValue += $card->getValue();
        $this->cards[] = $card;
    }

    function getTotalValue()
    {
        return $this->totalValue;
    }

    public function reset()
    {
        $this->totalValue = 0;
        $this->cards = array();
    }
}
```

Now you can get the value of the `Hand`:

```
$deck = new Deck();
$players[] = new Player("You");

// start with 5 cards
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $player->getHand()->drawCard($deck, 5);
}

// each player draws a card
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $player->getHand()->drawCard($deck);
}

// get totals
foreach ($players as $player) {
    print("Player: " . $player->getName() . "<br />");
    $player->getHand()->getTotalValue();
    print("<P>&nbsp;</p>");
}

// start again with new 5 cards
foreach ($players as $player) {
    $player->getHand()->drawCard($deck, 5, true); // reseting with the 3rd param
}
```

You don't need to prefix your class names with `class`, and public properties are considered "not done". Normal practice is to set all properties to protected at minimum, and add accessor functions (`get..()` and `set...()`)

And in this particular example, I would even consider merging the `Player` and `Hand` classes, because they kind of resemble the same thing. Unless the Player object is a generic user object you will reuse in many places of course.

Comment: Thank you SO much again NDM. It was very informative and useful. I did only add the addCard and getTotalValue functions and changed the last line of my drawCard function to match the last line in yours. So the changes could works together. And I used the same kind of FOR loop I used in my card page to display the totals which worked perfectly.

Comment: FYI even though my coding is not good and soon obsolete, I only did it this way to learn how to crawl a little first sort of speak, but your information on more improved methods will certainly help me better understand where i'm heading and with revamp my little card game soon to show off what you've taught me more so than this current one. So thank you! If I had a higher reputation I would vote your answer up.

Comment: no problem. I only warned you of you php4 coding style because this is so old it'll be removed. and that means a lot in php where backwards compatibility is the holy grail. happy coding :) (and btw, the downvote on ur question isnt mine... else I would remove it)

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawCard($c,$theDeck){
    if(is_numeric($c)){
        $c=floor($c);
        for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
            $this->cards[] = $theDeck->dealCard();
            $this->total += $theDeck->dealCard()->getValue();
        }
     }
}

function getTotal(){
   return $this->total;
}
```

Comment: When you are adding the value to the total, you are drawing a new card, it's not the value of the card you drew the line before.